# What's difference between case and match?

Tags: match, case, racket

I was confusing about the difference between `match` and `case`. In the [document](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match%29%29)， it mentions that `match` supports general pattern matching.

```
> (define (m x)
    (match x
      [(list a b c)
       #:when (= 6 (+ a b c))
       'sum-is-six]
      [(list a b c) 'sum-is-not-six]))
> (m '(1 2 3))
'sum-is-six

> (m '(2 3 4))
'sum-is-not-six
```

For this example, I thought I could rewrite it using `case` expression. But seems it's quite complicated. I have to get the length of the input `x`, and maybe a lambda function to get the sum of the elements of `x` and compare it with `6`.

So I guess we prefer `match` when doing pattern matching. Is it true? Any difference other than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said it yourself, `match` does general [*pattern matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) (a very powerful concept!) whereas `case` only checks if a value belongs in one of several lists of possible (implicitly quoted) values. All that `case` does is syntactic sugar for a `cond` with multiple conditions, for example:

```
(case (+ 7 5)
  [(1 2 3) 'small]
  [(10 11 12) 'big]
  [else 'other])
```

... is roughly equivalent to:

```
(let ((val (+ 7 5)))
  (cond ((or (equal? val 1) (equal? val 2) (equal? val 3))
        'small)
        ((or (equal? val 10) (equal? val 11) (equal? val 12))
        'big)
        (else 'other)))
```

Whereas `match` does some complex matching; it checks if a value is one of several possible *patterns*, it's not only about comparing values for equality, it also checks the type and "shape" of the value against the pattern, and we can even add additional constraints using `#:when`. To see how complex this can be check under the *grammar* part of `match`'s [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html?q=match#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match%29%29).

Answer (score 1):

There are two differences:

1. [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt)._match))) is a lot more powerful than [`case`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/case.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt)._case))). `case` doesn't have "patterns" in the way `match` does, and it implicitly quotes the datums in each "branch question". It only compares the quoted form of the datum against the value, like a switch statement. `match` has a different and much richer pattern language.

The `x` in each branch-question of these two examples

```
(case 5
  [(x) 10]
  [else 'fail])
;=> 'fail

(case 'x
  [(x) 10]
  [else 'fail])
;=> 10
```

Is implicitly quoted, as the symbol `'x`. In match terms, this is equivalent to

```
(match 5
  ['x 10]
  [_ 'fail])
;=> 'fail

(match 'x
  ['x 10]
  [_ 'fail])
;=> 10
```

Where quoting is one of many options for creating patterns, not the default. If you leave out the quote in a `match`, `x` is no longer a symbol; it is a wildcard that matches anything and defines `x` as the result.

```
(match 5
  [x (+ x 1)])
;=> 6
```

This could never happen with [`case`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/case.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt)._case))) because of `case`'s implicit quoting.

2. [`case`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/case.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt)._case))) branch-questions have multiple datums per branch.

These datums must be wrapped in parentheses.

```
(case expr
  [(datum ...) answer]
  ...)
```

Where `match` has only one pattern per branch (no parentheses)

```
(match expr
  [pattern answer]
  ...)
```